# Unable to delete the first value in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var check = /^[^-\s]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;
```

My html:

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onTextChange(e)} required/>
```

Function:

```
onTextChange(event) {
  let fieldVal = event.target.value;var check = /^\S+[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;
  if(check.test(fieldVal)){

  } else{

  }
}
```

If I use this in function to restrict space at beginning means it is working fine. But while entering backspace first character is not removing. Can any one help?

Comment: Can you post the code to your whole component?

Comment: Post a reproducible and understandable snippet of code not just a regex, the issue could be in how you use it

Comment: @vidhya, edit your question and add that code. Also, add code for `onTextChange`.

Comment: edited my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

This will remove any whitespaces before the string, if there are any, and won't prevent you from the backspacing issue you had either.

The regex: `/^\s+/` basically matches one or more (`+`) whitespace characters (`\s`) that is at the start of the string (`^`).

We replace this match with the empty string `''`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {val: ""};
  }
  
  onTextChange = (e) => {
    let str = e.target.value;
    str = str.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    this.setState({val: str});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.val} onChange={this.onTextChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```